# Need help with ugly nesting

Tags: jquery

How do I select the src of the image tag in the following code? I can't seem to get it right!

```
<li id="user001">
<div class="profile">
<span class="profileImage">
<img src="ladida.png" />
</span>
</div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var src = $('li#user001 img').attr('src');
```

Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 2):

```
var profileImageSrc = $("#user001 .profile .profileImage img").attr("src");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var profileImageSrc = $('.profile .profileImage img').attr('src');
```

But this assumes there's only one image. Since it's in a class `profileImage` there could be more than one, then you may have to rethink how you're going to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#user001 .profile .profileImage img").attr("src");
```

Comment: There is no item that matches the first part of your selector.

Comment: @sje397 -- looks exactly like yours

Comment: No, the spaces are important. As you have it, it's looking for an item with the id `user001` that has all those classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
alert($(".profile .profileImage img").attr("src"));
```